Calling ambulances without phones
Writing a story, and the world is advanced in the way that they have portals and cars but not things like phones or computers. How would a character call an ambulance without a phone? Asked a friend this question and was recommended this website.

Hi Banzy. Can you explain how the technology in your world works in general and some of its limitations? Without knowing a bit how your world works it can be pretty hard to give a good answer apart from assumptions based on historical evidence. If you're mainly looking for suggestions, r/worldbuilding on reddit is another great place to check out.

Arcane creates portals via magic. You can do anything you want with magic. Please note that we do not help people with quesitons about 3rd party or commercial worlds. Given your reference to Arcane in your post and your avatar being Jinx from Arcane/League of Legends, I need convincing that you're not writing fanfic - which means you're building onto somebody else's world - which is prohibited here. VTC:NAW(3rd Party/Commercial World)

@JBH It's not a fanfic, just a personal thing I'm writing but my worldbuilding is definitely inspired by Arcane. I didn't know that was against the rules, apologies!

Please [edit] your post and explain the specific differences between your imaginary world and the commercial world of Arcane. Also, when you have a moment, please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand the limits of this service. Thanks.

Removing the phrase "think Arcane" doesn't solve the problem. The cat's out of the bag. You actually need to explain the differences between your world and the commercial world.

Dude I'm not gonna lie to you I sat there for like 10 minutes yesterday and tried to explain but I am not that far into the story and I barely have my worldbuilding set up. I didn't know it was gonna get this serious, I'm sorry. I made a mistake, can't particularly fix it, and I won't do it again. Sorry if this comes off as rude I don't intend for that

I would expect good communications being a major part of being advanced. The next thing down from phone is either radio(wireless) or telegraph(wired). Do those exist?

Smoke Signal
You could use the smoke-signal principal, it could be a sort of pellet that they crush that sends up a colored smoke in the air to broadcast their location, or perhaps a device that sends a beam of light into the sky, the form it takes would kind of depend on the style of your world, but the principle could work in a myriad of settings.

or perhaps a device that sends a beam of light into the sky You just invented a flare. Having a flare gun in your dashboard could be a simple option.

The Way They Actually Did It
Before telephones, ambulances were still used to transport patients.  A runner was sent from wherever the patient was located to the nearest ambulance dispatch location.
Alternately, ambulances would be dispatched (like fire trucks or police) to locations likely to have casualties, like major crashes, industrial accidents, and similar disasters.
If the setting has magical portals, that would seem to cut down on logistics, though.  Why have an ambulance at all if you can roll a stretcher through a portal?

You could discworld it - and use semaphores (flags/lightsignals). But that requires a watchmen on a high tower in the center of the city, ready to see the request. (1 for the guard, 2 for the firebrigade, 3 for the ambulance).
Sound also comes to mind, bells in particular can be far carrying and placed high can be located using the time difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_location.
Similar to that, would be ground carried infra-sound. A drum or gong could also work here.
Finally- a semaphore version- could be fireworks, signalflares, coloured dust shot into the sky or just paper kites releases on a colored line to show where the wounded person is.
